# Silverlight datagrid elapsed time cell

Tags: silverlight, datagrid

In my silverlight application I use a data grid. I have a column with session started time and a column with elapsed time. The elapsed time is "total minutes : seconds". In my model I have a property ElapsedTimeDisplay that compute and transform the elapsed time into a string. 
How can update that each second? 
Is there any possibility to update only that column?
Is there any other possibility of achieving this without using a trigger?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This depends on your setup, it could be as easy as adding a timer in your ViewModel (or maybe your model) that ticks every second, and raise the `PropertyChanged` event on the `ElapsedTimeDisplay` (which I suppose does the calculation in the getter). To do this, you need to have your ViewModel (or model) implement `INotifyPropertyChanged`.

Hope this helps :)